# Image Property Tag Constant

Tags: .net, gdi+, exif, imaging

I'd like to use the [image property tag constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534413(VS.85).aspx) defined in GDI+ from .NET.

I wonder whether these constant values (**e.g. PropertyTagGpsVer constant**) are exposed in any of the Base Class Library?

I have tried looking around System.Drawing.Imaging namespace to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are not.

Enumeration of the tags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534417(VS.85).aspx
Long description of the tags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534416(VS.85).aspx

I ended up copying and pasting most of these two pages into code in order to do what you want: have a set of constants. You'll need to implement a set of PropertyItems by name and pre-populate them with the id, length, and type of the PropertyItem.

The other way to do it is t just choose the constants you need and implement them.

Comment: Imho it's much more clear to build a real C# enum from these constants, and switch/case on it. Numerical order here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-tags-in-numerical-order

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Microsoft SDKs, you can find all the constants in a C header file named GdiPlusImaging.h

It would be simple enough to include the header in a C project, but you'd have to do some tweaking to put them all into enumerations.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for the `System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem` class. See a description and an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.aspx)

Comment: I'm looking for the constant values for the ID property in PropertyItem.